# Select a single datatype array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

I got a `JSON.stringify`:

```js
var IDData = JSON.stringify([

  ["Environmental dynamics of Piscirickettsia Salmonis", "Piscirickettsia Salmonis", "Customer", "patongenoA", "Proyecto39", "40", "100", "1445837"],
  ["Piscirickettsia Salmonis", "Microbiología y Parasitología", "patogenoA", "Microbiología y Parasitología", "Proyecto40", "40", "100", "1445837"],
  ["Microbiología y Parasitología", "Protocolo", "Microbiología y Parasitología", "Protocolo", "Proyecto41", "40", "100", "1445837"],

]);

proyectos = JSON.parse(IDData);
// alert( numbers );
alert(proyectos[0]);
```

and show it and alert with this message appear:

```
Environmental dynamics of Piscirickettsia Salmonis,Piscirickettsia Salmonis,Customer,patongenoA,Proyecto39,40,100,1445837
```

an array, all separate with commas.

Is there any chance, to select only one data of the array? Example: "Alert:"`Proyecto40`

Is there any chance, using Javascript, to select one single data type and convert it to a variable?

thanks in advance,

Comment: The value stored at `proyectos[0]` is also an array so... `proyectos[1][4]` would be `Proyecto40`

Comment: What would you expect `Proyecto40` to be? What value would that be and why?

Comment: Is there any chance to select all like: the`proyectos[i][4]` and list them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the position :

```
var myVar = proyectos[1][4]
```

Deep destructure ( knowing the position ) :

```
var [, [, , , , myVar1]] = proyectos
```

Array.filter() :

```
var myVar2 = proyectos.flat().filter(e => e === 'Proyecto40')[0];
```

```js
var IDData = JSON.stringify([

  ["Environmental dynamics of Piscirickettsia Salmonis", "Piscirickettsia Salmonis", "Customer", "patongenoA", "Proyecto39", "40", "100", "1445837"],
  ["Piscirickettsia Salmonis", "Microbiología y Parasitología", "patogenoA", "Microbiología y Parasitología", "Proyecto40", "40", "100", "1445837"],
  ["Microbiología y Parasitología", "Protocolo", "Microbiología y Parasitología", "Protocolo", "Proyecto41", "40", "100", "1445837"],

]);

proyectos = JSON.parse(IDData);
// alert( numbers );

var myVar = proyectos[1][4]
console.log(myVar);

var [, [, , , , myVar1]] = proyectos
console.log(myVar1);

var myVar2 = proyectos.flat().filter(e => e === 'Proyecto40')[0];
console.log(myVar2)
```

Comment: The function `flat` is not a good choice here because of repeated values in different arrays.